# Understanding baptism entry in 1718 from Rockensüß

Tags: germany, transcriptions, german-language, translation, hesse

I'm trying to understand this baptism entry:

[image]

I have transcribed it to read:

```
d. 28. ejusd. h. mat. 1. Joh. Märtin 
Christoph. 

mit Cath. Schweitzer alh. in ein
ehlichtes erz. Söhnl. n. Joh.n.
Märtin Jacobs, Joh., Joh. [Holst?]
Niedmöllers [d.?] Joh. Ad., Adam
Hohmanns Sohn, bapt. d. seq. 4 Xbr
```

The prior entry was from 9br, aka November.

As I read it, this is the baptism entry for Joh. Märtin Christoph _____, son of Cath(erine) Schweitzer from 'here', ie Rockensüß, who was born on the 28th of November and baptised in Rockensüß on the 4th of December in 1718.

I'm pretty sure that this was an illegitimate child, and I think the remainder is giving the name of the father, and perhaps his father's name as well (the miller in the Niedermühle?).  But I can't understand that part of the text well enough.

There was a Niedermühle outside of Berneburg, which is only 2 km away.

So, assuming my partial understanding is correct, who was the father (and grandfather), and which was the miller in the Niedermühle?

Comment: Alternate transcription ...ein un- ehlicher erz[eugtes] Söhnl[ein] ... [and the following names are the 3? godparents]

Comment: That makes a good deal of sense; illegitimate children often were assigned multiple godparents, if only to avoid casting undeserved 'blame' on a single individual or their immediate family...